# Retrieving order of GET array parameters in PHP

Tags: php

I need to keep or somehow determine the original order of array parameters provided as query string parameters.

Ie. the requested URL is `/?a[]=x&b[]=y&a[]=z`. When accessing the parameters through `$_GET`, PHP parses the values into two arrays, from which I cannot determine that the third `a[]=z` parameter was specified after the second `b[]=y`.

```
// Request URL is index.php?a[]=x&b[]=y&a[]=z
print_r($_GET);

// Or equivalent, as I actually work with the query string, not with $_GET
parse_str('a[]=x&b[]=y&a[]=z', $params);
print_r($params);

// Output
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => z
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => y
        )

)
```

What I want is to have something like this:

```
[
    'a',
    'b',
    'a',
]
```

... or anything similar from which could the original order be determined.

Is there any way how to achieve this except from writing custom query string parser?

Comment: You'll have to check the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` yourself then.

Comment: Could assign indexes as they are set. `a[1]=x&b[2]=y&a[3]=z`. Can re-order the keys later after you have collected the key information you need.

Comment: I don't see a practical application for this.  Maybe if you explained what you're trying to do in general, there may be a better way.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The URL is assembled on client side, and it need to be provided back to the client (through an json object) on different page, where it must be possible to determine the original order.

Comment: The question is "why" _must it be possible to determine the original order_?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Because it is important :-). In the query string there are data provided by the user, and they must be presented to the user in exact same order on different page, so that the user won't be confused. I see why you are asking, but should it be some common use-case, I wouldn't be asking there.

Answer (score 0):

You need parse Query string yourself, because usage of array in form or get parameters is for grouping values.

For your purpose you can use this:

```
$queryParameters = explode('&',$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
$postData = array();
foreach($queryParameters as $queryParameter){
    list($key, $value) = explode('[]=', $queryParameter);
    $postData[] = array(
        'key' => $key,
        'value' => $value
    );
}
```

It returns this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "x"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "y"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "z"
  }
}
```

But i think will be better change keys of query parameters. If you describe what you need, it will be easiest to help you with right solution.